# Check my argument for this proof for Quotient Rule (limits)

Tags: limits, analysis, alternative-proof

I have seen that calculus books have other ways to prove this theorem (involving triangle inequality). Just wanted to know if this reasoning is okay or I have done some circular reasoning in this proof.

**Given** : $\lim_{x\to a}$ g(x) = M

**To prove** : $\lim_{x\to a} {1 \over g(x)} = {1 \over M}$

**Proof** :

For every $\epsilon$>0, we have to find a $\delta$>0 such that, whenever 0<|x-a|<$\delta$

it implies: $|\frac{1}{g(x)}-\frac{1}{M}|<\epsilon$

or $|\frac{M-g(x)}{g(x).M}|<\epsilon$

or $\frac{|g(x)-M|}{|g(x)|.|M|}<\epsilon$

or $|g(x)-M|<\epsilon$.|g(x)|.|M|

As $\lim_{x\to a}$ g(x) = M, therefore we can find a $\delta_1$>0 such that, whenever 0<|x-a|<$\delta_1$

it implies: $|g(x)-M|<\epsilon$.|g(x)|.|M| (because $\epsilon$.|g(x)|.|M|>0)

finally, choose $\delta$ < $\delta_1$

so the condition, whenever 0<|x-a|<$\delta$

it implies: $|\frac{1}{g(x)}-\frac{1}{M}|<\epsilon$, is satisfied

Therefore, limit is true.

Comment: I think it does not work. Although $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, you can not choose it to be dependent on $x$, since it causes $\delta$ to be not only depending on $\epsilon$ but also on $x$. This additional restriction may causes $\delta$ not to exist.

Comment: You need to assume  $M\ne0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not correct. The fact that $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=M$ means that for each *constant* $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that $\lvert x-a\rvert<\delta\implies\bigl\lvert g(x)-M\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon$. You applied this to $\varepsilon'=\varepsilon.\bigl\lvert g(x)\bigr\rvert.M$, which is *not* a constant, since it depends upon $x$.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The reason you just mentioned is exactly what book is trying to do i.e. replacing somehow g(x) with M, so that the right hand is independent of x. But let me ask you this, we know that |g(x)| > 0. Therefore, $\epsilon$.|M|.|g(x)| is always >0. For every number >0 for |g(x)-M|, we can find a matching $\delta$>0. Is that not the meaning of the term 'limit exists'?

Comment: No. It's for every *fixed* number, not a changing one.

Comment: @HarwinderSingh: you need to get the definition correct. $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, but once chosen it behaves as a constant, next comes $\delta$ which depends on $\epsilon$ and once it is determined it also remains fixed. The variable $x$ on the other hand varies but its range of values are controlled by $\delta $ via $0<|x-a|<\delta$. $x$ comes into existence only when $\epsilon, \delta$ are already available. Don't try to put $\epsilon, \delta, x$ on same footing.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Thanks that makes it quite clear, for not including x in the expression of $\delta$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks, now the your original answer makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

It's not correct. First, you must have $M\neq 0$. Now, the fact that $g(x)\to M$ when $x\to a$ gives you that $|g(x)|\geq \frac{|M|}{2}$ when $|x-a|<\delta $ for some $\delta >0$. Therefore, $$\frac{|g(x)-M|}{|g(x)||M|}\leq \frac{|g(x)-M|}{2M^2}.$$

I let you finish the proof.